# Windows 10 lock powershell file for reading and writing but not for executing

Tags: powershell, locking

Is is possible to lock a powershell file for reading and writing but it can be still run with righ click --> Run with Powershell??

thank you

Comment: What are you trying to solve exactly? Depending, there might be better ways to get this accomplished or remind you about security though obscurity.

Comment: I am running a bat procedure on another server. The reason I want to disable reading is to hide some passwords/usernames that are stored inside the procedure

Answer (score 2):

You can deny the write-access. But to execute a script you have to be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Truly securing the credential information is only going to happen through some form of delegation as a layer between the read-able script and the credentials. There are a lot of resources out there for learning about how to securely store passwords for use in scripts.

Try reading about some of the recommendations here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8b14f492-88a2-4b25-9ae6-5278a1a8735d/hiding-password-in-the-script?forum=winserverpowershell

If privileged users are the only ones who can read the file, then perhaps you just want an example of obfuscation (relies on trust as it can still be used by those who can read the script):
http://blog.ctglobalservices.com/powershell/rja/store-encrypted-password-in-a-powershell-script/